# Show onclick hidden div above another div using z-index

Tags: html, css

[image: menu must float above table-list-div]I need to show a hidden menu (dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right) above his parent div (table-list-div always-visible).

When i click on the button just half of the menu is show, another half stays hidden  inside the parent div.

How can i show all the menu wixh is a div that needs to show above his parent div.

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        .table-list-div {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            border:1px solid blue;
        }
        .table-list-results {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 20;
        }
        .paging {
            position: relative;
            background:#f6f6f6;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        .dropdown-menu-right
        {
            border:15px solid orange;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 500;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="table-list-div always-visible">
        <table class="table-list-results">
            <tr>
                <td class="actions">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More</button>
                        <ul  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"  >
                            <li ><a href="/action/abc/def">see</a></li>
                            <li ><a href="/action/ghi">cancel</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="paging paging-bottom center"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so if i understand your question you need to make appear an hidden menu by clicking on a visible part manipulating the z-index.

To do this in javascript you can manipulate the z-index using

```
var elem = document.getElementById('yourid');
elem.style.zIndex = 0;
```

You can triggered the onclick event to a function that called something similar to what i purpose above.

Comment: Can this be done just with CSS? the problem happen just after i do add the div around the table:  `<div class="table-list-div always-visible">`

Comment: just by css yes and no. One way to do this is to set a class with the good z-index but you will need javascript to on the click event add or remove the class to the good element with class list : div.classList.add("anotherclass");   one link to see how run classlist https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: I am using bootstrap dropdow-menu class to show the menu when clicking, looking how to trigger the onclick event.

Comment: do you have an id or a class you can recover in javascript ? then you can use something near : yourelem.addEventListener("click", function(){//your action}

Comment: Yes i can addd an id, just figuring out now, how to add the javascript code into CakePHP 2.

Comment: just write : <td id="listaction" class="actions" onclick="document.getElementById('table-list-div').style.zIndex=0">, could not see the menu above the table-list-div wich i set to 0 , dropdown-menu-right already have z-index: 500. Is there any extra step ?

Comment: maybe there is quote between the 0. Have you an error in the console of the browser ?

Comment: Yes! Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Fix the syntaxError, now when i click the button and inspect on chrome it point to the .btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle bootstrap library selector. Also i do generate an inline javascript to alter z-index property, from table-div-list: <td id="actionlist" class="actions" onclick="document.getElementById(table-list-div).style.zIndex=0">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113636/discussion-between-angelo-rigo-and-jeremy-denis).